# find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: command-line

I am having problem with the find and grep commands. I want to find the files which are `*.doc` and match the pattern `Danish` from that file with grep command. I am using -exec to combine them but it give an error i do not know what is that. It said that the `-exec` argument is missing.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. And there should be a space between `{}` and `+` or `;`.

Comment: And if you're using `;` escape it: `\;`.

Comment: That's a typical beginner's mistake which I also made quite a few times until I found that out... ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You have to escape the `;`:

```
find -iname .... -exec echo {} \;
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: The space before it is also mandatory, otherwise you get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you put a backslash before the `;`, the shell will interpret that as a command separator, not as an argument to `find` command.

Comment: *And* a space before it, otherwise you get the same error.